# No JAXB Classes Generated from xsd using Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

am not able see any of jaxb classes generated from my xsd using jaxb2-maven-plugin

```
    <bulid>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>

            <schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
<sourceGenerationDirectory>target/sources</sourceGenerationDirectory>
<classGenerationDirectory>target/classes</classGenerationDirectory>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    </bulid>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

and i ran my pom by giving
clean install generate:generate is that a correct way ? please suggest a way to generate jaxb classes

i even tried to run by mvn generate-sources nothing is getting generated

Comment: please find above what i have tried

Comment: Well I think the question has changed. Previously you were asking about how to. Now, after edition, it looks like you know the how to, but the solution is not working... just guessing because you did not comment the result of your solution. Any error?

Comment: No plugin found for perfix 'generate' am getting something like this

Comment: 1) Don't add the plugin as a dependency... 2) Read and understand everything here: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide  3) Try again yourself 4) Come back here and ask again. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just changed my goal to xjc and mvn jaxb2:xjc it worked i was able to get the jxb classes generated

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me at some point in time; you can work from there:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.tools.xjc.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
        <includeBindings>
            <includeBinding>*.xjb</includeBinding>
        </includeBindings>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The plugin is bound to the `generate-sources` phase.

Cheers,

Comment: i tired what you have asked me to do nothing is getting generated under target folder..

Comment: Edit your original question and paste in whatever relevant output maven gives you, otherwise we're *really* unable to help you out...

Comment: i have changed my question now please suggest a way